# Explaining deadlocks with a single lock from The Little Go Book

Tags: go, mutex

I'm reading [The Little Go Book](https://www.openmymind.net/assets/go/go.pdf).

Page 76 demonstrates how you can deadlock with a single lock:

```golang
var (
    lock sync.Mutex
)

func main() {
    go func() { lock.Lock() }()
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 10)
    lock.Lock()
}
```

Running this results in a deadlock as explained by the author.  However, what I don't understand is why.

I changed the program to this:

```golang
var (
    lock sync.Mutex
)

func main() {
    go func() { lock.Lock() }()
    lock.Lock()
}
```

My expectation was that a deadlock would still be thrown.  But it wasn't.

Could someone explain to me what's happening here please?

The only scenario I can think of that explains this is the following (but this is guesswork):

**First example**

1. The lock is acquired in the first goroutine
2. The call to `time.Sleep()` ensures the lock is acquired
3. The `main` function attempts to acquire the lock resulting in a deadlock
4. Program exits

**Second example**

1. The lock is acquired in the first goroutine but this takes some time to happen (??)
2. Since there is no delay the `main` function acquires the lock before the goroutine can
3. Program exits

Comment: I think the program exits before the goroutine even starts without the delay.

Comment: Also note the first example isn’t guaranteed to deadlock either, it just happens to under most reasonable circumstances with the standard Go implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, main sleeps long enough to give the child goroutine the opportunity to start and acquire the lock. That goroutine then will merrily exit without releasing the lock.

By the time main resumes its control flow, the shared mutex is locked so the next attempt to acquire it will block forever. Since at this point main is the only routine left alive, blocking forever results in a deadlock.

---

In the second example, without the call to `time.Sleep`, main proceeds straight away to acquire the lock. This succeeds, so main goes ahead and exits. The child goroutine *would* then block forever, but since main has exited, the program just terminates, without deadlock.

By the way, even if main didn't exit, as long as there is at least one goroutine which is not blocking, there's no deadlock. For this purpose, `time.Sleep` is not a blocking operation, it simply pauses execution for the specified time duration.

Answer (score 1):

`go` shows the deadlock error when **all** `goroutines` (including the main) are asleep.

in your first example, the inside `goroutine` is executed and terminated after he call `mutex.Lock()`. then the main goroutine tries to lock again but it goes `asleep` waiting for the opportunity to occupy the lock. so now we have all the goroutines(the main one) in the program in asleep mode which will cause a deadlock error !

it is **important** to understand this because a deadlock may happen but it will not always show an error if there still a running goroutine. which mostly what will happen in production. error will be reported only when the whole program get in a deadlock.